# node fs.readFileSync('/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist', 'utf8') mismatch the original content

Tags: macos

```
var content = fs.readFileSync('/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist', 'utf8');
var res = plist.parse(content);
console.log(res);
```

The console print

```
{
  ProductBuildVersion: '20G165',
  ProductCopyright: '1983-2021 Apple Inc.',
  ProductName: 'Mac OS X',
  ProductUserVisibleVersion: '10.16',
  ProductVersion: '10.16',
  iOSSupportVersion: '14.7'
}
```

But go to terminal print the content

```
➜  ~  cat /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
    <string>20G165</string>
    <key>ProductCopyright</key>
    <string>1983-2021 Apple Inc.</string>
    <key>ProductName</key>
    <string>macOS</string>
    <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
    <string>11.6</string>
    <key>ProductVersion</key>
    <string>11.6</string>
    <key>iOSSupportVersion</key>
    <string>14.7</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The version is different in two outputs. Does anyone know why they print different result?

Comment: What is the value of `content`? Maybe the issue is with the parsing library.

Comment: Most likely because of this https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/13/macos-version-numbering-isnt-so-simple/